# Publicly accessible forms web app with great photo tools

Tags: photography, forms, survey, saas

I am looking for something like TypeForm:

- I can easily edit a form (survey)
- I can publish it and share the link with people publicly
- Is free for unlimited public submissions (you're charged for the account/surveys instead)
- I get notified of submissions
- I can use that data with another application
- It's a Saas Web App platform

However, TypeForm doesn't have a photo field type. You can use the file selection, which can work, but I'm looking for a perfect match here.

The ideal software would:

- Use `getUserMedia`
- Display a preview of the "environment" camera (outward facing)
- A button to take the picture
- Functions for cropping
- Other photo colour correction tools
- The optional ability to find a photo or take a photo with another mobile app of choice

There are certainly software libraries to do all this, but I'm trying to bootstrap.